# Tooltip alignment

Tags: html, css, tooltip, alignment

How can I change the CSS so, that the tooltip shows up from right to left? Exactly the opposite of now.

http://jsfiddle.net/Q55C8/

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

write like this :

```
.tooltip span.info {
    display:none;
    position: absolute;
    white-space:nowrap;
    border-radius: 5px 5px; -moz-border-radius: 5px; -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px rgba(0, 0,0, 0.1);
    -moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    font-family: Calibri, Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    margin-left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    top:20px;
    right:0;
}
```

check this http://jsfiddle.net/sandeep/Q55C8/5/

Comment: Thanks for your help! I need this dynamically which means `right: -146px` is not correct for my problem. You can see the effect when you change the width of the `td`. Have you any another idea?

Comment: You are so good, thank you very much. I have just another little question? How do I have to change the code so that the "tooltip" is centered in the `td`?

Answer (score 0):

Just set the position of your tooltip to absolute (position fixed, fixes the tooltip relative to the window and not yout link) and adjust the position using the `right:xx` css style.

```
a.tooltip:hover span.info { display: block; position: absolute; right:-146px }
```

Demo

http://jsfiddle.net/Q55C8/4/

Comment: The link is set to position relative, he can bypass that by setting the td as position relative but since i don't know his setup i tried to make as little changes as possible.